# How to run React code from inner HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a pretty complex HTML file resulted after PDF parsing. And I have a React application, where I need to show this file and add event listeners for some nodes. The html file is inserted using `dangerouslysetinnerhtml` after fetching from the server. I came up with solution to add these functions for corresponding nodes while parsing on the back-end side and the question is how do I access my React code from this html file? Or maybe there any good alternatives to my approach? Thanks.

Comment: React, works best when been reactive.  IOW, you dont alter its state from outside.  With this in mind, having whats called a single source of truth would be handy here.  Have you looked at Redux?

Answer (score 0):

Just put event listeners on your existing html node identifiers using JQuery.

```
Ex. $('#YOUR_HTML_NODE').click()
```

No need to change the original HTML code if you do it this way.